# Google App Engine Error: No matching index found. (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am writing a query but it always says "No matching index found". I don't know why. My code is as below:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Classified.class);
query.setFilter("emp_Id == emp");
query.setOrdering("upload_date desc");
query.declareParameters("String emp");
List<Classified> results = (List<Classified>)query.execute(session.getAttribute("emp_Id").toString());
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
  <datastore-index kind="Classified" ancestor="false">
    <property name="emp_Id" direction="asc" />
    <property name="category" direction="asc" />
    <property name="upload_date" direction="desc" />
  </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

I have added the above index, but it did not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to configure a [Datastore Index](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig.html). There's probably one already generated for you in Eclipse at `WEB-INF/appengine-generated/datastore-indexes-auto.xml` that you just need to copy to `WEB-INF/datastore-indexes.xml` and deploy again.

Comment: For above query or table can you define how to create the datastore index

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <datastore-indexes
  autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="Classified" ancestor="false">
        <property name="emp_Id" direction="asc" />
        <property name="category" direction="asc" />
        <property name="upload_date" direction="desc" />
    </datastore-index>
     
    </datastore-indexes> i have added above but no help with..Can u help me..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes
  autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="Classified" ancestor="false">
        <property name="emp_Id" direction="asc" />
        <property name="category" direction="asc" />
        <property name="upload_date" direction="desc" />
    </datastore-index>
    
</datastore-indexes>

Answer (score 3):

Because this needs to be somewhere on the internet...

I kicked myself when I found this out
The error is you do not have a index matching what the query would like to perform. You can have multiple indexes for each entity.

In the Logcat, error, it will tell you exactly what index to set and what order the elements need to be.

ie, if the error says it wants (it wont be nicely formatted):

```
<datastore-index kind="Classified" ancestor="false">
    <property name="category" direction="desc" />
    <property name="upload_date" direction="desc" />
  </datastore-index>
```

then Project -> war -> WEB-INF -> appengine-generated -> datastore-indexes-auto.xml and add exactly that. Then, redeploy the project.

Next go into your Google Cloud Console and look at Datastore -> indexes. It should say that the index is being prepared (This goes quicker if you can kill all apps connected and shut down the instance in the console).

Once this has moved into the list of other indexes, rerun the your application and it wont error out with regards to the index anymore.

Go get it Gentlemen/Ladies

Comment: Just to update the answer - xml file is no longer used but index.yaml instead. As described here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig

Answer (score 1):

The index you define must hold all possible results in the order they will be returned.  Your query asks for a particular emp_Id, ordered by upload_date, but your index is ordered primarily by category.

Try removing the category line from your index definition, <s>or swapping the order of `category` and `upload_date`,</s> to make `upload_date` the primary sort order for the index.  If another part of your code relies on the category line, you may have to make two separate indices (which incurs some computational cost).

Edit: see comment below by Nick Johnson re. extra parameters.

Comment: Swapping the two won't help - App Engine can't use an index that has extra properties in it that aren't used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I am running into this issue at the moment when doing a single property query such as:

```
 const query = datastore
  .createQuery('Emailing_dev')
  .filter('status', '=', 'Scheduled')
```

In my case, I should not be getting any errors, however I get Error 9: No matching index found.

If I defined the single property index twice in the yaml, it works:

```
indexes:
  - kind: Emailing_dev
    properties:
    - name: status
    - name: status
```

but this for sure must be a bug..!!