# Objectify index is not created

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, objectify

I try to use objectify on google app engine standart environment and get exception. My classes look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    @Id Long id;
    @Index String companyName;

    public Company() {
    }

    public Company(Long id, String companyName) {
        this.id=id;
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
}

@Entity
public class CompanyProject {
    @Id Long id;
    @Index String projectName;
    @Parent Key<Company> owner;

    public String cost;

    public CompanyProject() {
    }

    public CompanyProject(long userId, String projectName) {
        this();
        this.projectName = projectName;
        owner = Key.create(Company.class, userId); // Creating the Ancestor key
    }
}
```

When I query data like this:

```
Key<Company> theUser = Key.create(Company.class, 1);
Iterable<CompanyProject> projects = ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(CompanyProject.class).ancestor(theUser).order("projectName").list();
```

I get exception

```
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: CompanyProject
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: projectName
```

Without order("projectName") query works just fine. Removed all entities of this kind from datastore, than added new, still get this exception. I use Gradle, not Maven if this matters. Maybe should be extra build step to create indexes or smth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine Error: No matching index found. (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403080/google-app-engine-error-no-matching-index-found-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering on multiple properties (well, ancestor counts as 'another property') so you need a multi-property index defined in `datastore-indexes.xml`.

See the official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/indexconfig